# CSS позиционирование элементов

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток!
Никак не могу выровнять центральные блоки относительно левых без потери отступов, наставьте на путь истинный.

HTML:

```
  <div class="left">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
    <div class="rightcontainer">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcontainer2">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="middle">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
    <div class="middlecontainer">

    </div>

    <div class="middlecontainer">

    </div>

    <div class="middlecontainer">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Левая секция*/

  .rightcontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 278px;
    height: 169px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px #dde0e1;

  }

    .rightcontainer2 {
    width: 278px;
    height: 655px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px #dde0e1;
  }

/*Левая секция*/

/*Центральная секция*/

  .middlecontainer {
    position: block;
    width: 675px;
    height: 230px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 22.5%;
    top: -5%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    box-shadow: 2px #dde0e1;
  }
/*Левая секция*/
```

[image: Выровнять]

Comment: Честно говоря, совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите относительно чего и как выровнять.

Comment: А можно полный код который вы написали. Непосредственно html.

Comment: Есть левые блоки, есть те что идут по центру, мне нужно что-бы те что идут по центру стояли на одном уровне с теми, что идут по левому краю. Но отступ между блоками по центру должен остаться тот же

Comment: Прикрепил разметку..

Comment: Что значит на одном уровне? По верхней границе? Ширина как-то должна поменяться? Растянуться по высоте на ту же величину?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/92sytLzm/ Примерно так?

Comment: Да, благодарю. :)